# Is my soymilk curdled?

Tags: soymilk

I made some soymilk yesterday using the recipe specified below-

[How to Make Soy Milk, from Scratch (豆浆)(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9nxEsNe84U)

RECIPE:

Ingredients:

Soybeans, 200g
Water, 2.4L
Sugar, to taste (we used 3 tbsp)
Process:

Pick out any bad soybeans, rinse.
Put your water ~2 inches above your soybeans, soak overnight.
Blend on high for ~4 minutes. We used the smoothie setting on our blender.
Transfer to a wok or stockpot. Medium high flame.
Stir and get the soymilk up to 100C.
Boil at 100C for 15 minutes, removing the foam.
Taste, make sure it's not bitter.
Strain through a tofu or cheesecloth. Twist and squeeze out what's left, ~3-5 minutes. Get as much as you can!
Season with sugar, to taste. We used ~3 tbsp.

It has been one day and the upper layer is bubbly. It does not smell sour but there is the fragrance of raw soaked soybeans. The milk has become thick and there are smooth chunks of semi solid material, not rough and sharp like there are in usual curdled soymilk.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has oxidized and turned, unfortunately... When making Tofu, you almost instantly "pasteurise" the soy juice into milk almost as soon as it has been blended by bringing it to a boil, this prevents the soy juice from "turning"... Unfortunately, this also starts (partially) the process of curdling the soy milk into curds for tofu.

You will find that long life soy milk has very little fridge life after it has been opened, this is the bad side of consuming high protein "juices" such as soy, and nut milk, and would be a constant enemy if you want to make your own soy juice/milk.